# Append values without commas

Tags: python

I am trying to write a loop that writes a text file with values seperated by spaces only. For some reason python is inserting brackets at the beginning and end as well as commas between each value. I have tried join and a couple other methods but have not been succesful.

```
Here is my code: 
import os
import numpy

os.chdir('/Users/DevEnv/Case_1')


try:
    os.remove('fparameters.txt')
except OSError:
    pass

n=50
N=50

tlength=1501  #set number of generations 



for x in range(0,n):
    A=[]
    for i in range(0,tlength):
        Aj=[]
        for v in range(0,N):
            mu_f, sigma_f = 1.5, 0.5  
            Aj.append(60+ numpy.random.lognormal(mu_f, sigma_f, size=None))     

        A.append(Aj)

    outFile = open('fparameters.txt','a')
    for item in A:
        outFile.write('%s ' %item)
    outFile.write('\n')
    outFile.close()
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Please format your code to properly reflect your actual script. It’s impossible to tell how blocks are nested otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A` is a list of lists of numbers, so `item` is a list of numbers here:

```
for item in A:
    outFile.write('%s ' %item)
```

To create a string from an iterable of strings, you can use `str.join`. You have a list of numbers, though, so you’ll need to convert each one to a string with `str()`:

```
for item in A:
    outFile.write(' '.join(str(x) for x in item))
```

If the `outFile.write('\n')` really isn’t indented and you want everything on one line, it might be best to just flatten the list of lists of numbers into one iterable of strings:

```
with open('fparameters.txt', 'a') as f:
    print(' '.join(str(x) for item in A for x in item), file=f)
```